# Rank of $AA^T$ if $A$ is a full rank matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, matrix-rank

Assume we have $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, $rg(A) = m$. Will $\det(AA^T)$ be non-zero? Same question is for $\det(\Phi^T\Phi)$, where $\Phi \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}, rg(\Phi) = m$.

Comment: What exactly does "rg" stand for?

Comment: rank of matrix A

Comment: Presumably $m \le n$?

Comment: I think $rank(A) = m$ stands for $m <= n$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is true: if $A$ is $m \times n$ with rank $m$, then $\det(AA^T)$ will be non-zero. Similarly, if $A$ is $m \times n$ with rank $n$, then $\det(A^TA)$ will be non-zero.

There are a few ways you could go about proving this. One is to use the fact that
$$
\operatorname{rank}(A) = \operatorname{rank}(A^TA) = \operatorname{rank}(AA^T),
$$
and a square matrix will have non-zero determinant if and only if its rank is equal to its size. Alternatively, you could use the [Cauchy Binet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Binet_formula) formula to express either determinant as a sum of squares.

Comment: I am sorry, but I cannot understand the $rank(A^TA) = rank(AA^T)$ transition. Could you please explain, because I have a feeling that I miss something fundamental about this thing?

Comment: @Blinkop It is simply a fact that $\operatorname{rank}(A) = \operatorname{rank}(A^TA)$ and $\operatorname{rank}(A) = \operatorname{rank}(AA^T)$. The fact that this holds in the case that $A$ has full rank is proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3665926/81360), but if you're interested I could either write or point you to a more general proof

Comment: @Blinkop [Here is a proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/349738/81360) for the more general result.